# Why inputs width fit on flexbox and not grid?

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox, css-grid

I'm using `flex` and `grid` to `display` two HTML forms. With flex **inputs** fit inside form size, however with grid they don't.

HTML

```html
  <form class="flex">
    inputs in a flex column
    <input placeholder="name">
    <input placeholder="age">
  </form>  
  
  <form class="grid">
    inputs in a grid
    <input placeholder="name">
    <input placeholder="age">
  </form
```

CSS

```css
form {
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}

form.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form.grid {
  display: grid;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tfv8wrLp/

Why inputs width fit on flexbox and not grid?

Comment: Add `min-width:0` to the `input` elements.

Comment: Awesome @Paulie_D but why I don't need to add that change with flexbox?